# Javascript `http-proxy-middleware` onProxyRes and onProxyReq signature parameters

Tags: javascript, express, signature, http-proxy-middleware

I'm new to Javascript, and it's a mind bending world to me.

I have a **[web app]** that talks to a **[proxy]** that talks to a **[web service]**.

In the signature, `onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res)`, where do each of the parameters originate? It seems like all documentation assumes you already know how it works.

So far, it seems obvious to me `req` was the original request, does this mean `res` is the original response? If I am trying to inject headers, should I be updating `proxyRes`?

I'm having a CORS error, I believe I just need to inject the header...

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware
indicates how to use this feature.

```
function onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
  proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
}
```

should work.
However, I haven't gotten my example to work yet, so I am hoping another reply will come in, or you have it figured out now.